# Are all functions whose integral doesn't vanish over an infinitesimal slice, expressible as a dirac delta function?

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

If I have a function $f(x)$ integrated over an infinitesimal slice, where for $\epsilon > 0$ $$\tag{1} \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} f(x)dx = 1$$

Then is it true that $f(x)$ can always be expressed in terms of the dirac delta function like so
$$f(x) = g(x) + a\delta(x) $$ where $g(x)$ is a function of $x$,  $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant, and $\delta(x)$ is the dirac delta function. Or are there other special functions/cases I'm missing, where a function integrated over an infinitesimal slice doesn't vanish?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Dirac delta function". There IS, however, a Dirac delta *distribution*. Do you know about distributions?

Comment: "Delta function" isn't a function, it's, depending on context, either measure, or generalized function.

Comment: @MiloMoses I really dislike this response, standard as it is; it's pedantic.  There are a bunch of ways to formalize the delta function without the standard theory of distributions; you can just build a field of convolution fractions, for example...

Comment: @user3716267 The point I was trying to get at with 'one two' is that these things aren't strictly functions, and that we have to consider what space we're working in. You don't necessarily have to use distributions (though this is obviously my preferred method), but a priori you'll get different answers to the post depending on which space we're working in

Comment: That's a totally valid point; I think it's better to say that directly, than to say that "the delta function is not a function."  For someone still thinking about these things heuristically, that answer doesn't clarify anything.  You can even give an example of two spaces in which the answer might be different!

Comment: @MiloMoses  Unfortunately I am not familiar with distributions or measures. As such I am actually not sure how to reformulate my question. I am attempting to assign a general trait of functions who's integral does not vanish as the path/interval over which you integrate does. As such I was wondering if they were all expressible in terms of a dirac delta.  If curious for background on why, you guys can check my last question regarding line integrals, and the answers on comments on it.

Comment: Why don't you allow $g(x)=f(x)$ and $a=0$?

Comment: If you mean for any $\epsilon>0$, why $f(x)=g(x)+a\delta(x)$ and not $f(x)=\delta(x)$? Usually these are limit representations of the Dirac delta function such as $\delta(x)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\int\limits_{-f}^f e^{2 i \pi t x}\,dt\right)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(2 f\ \text{sinc}(2 \pi f x)\right)$ (see https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/DiracDelta/09/). More precisely, the definition of $f_n \to \delta$ is $\forall \phi \in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}), \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_n(x)\phi(x)dx\to \phi(0)$.

Comment: @MiloMoses I believe that actually pins down the essence of my question, if a function $f(x)$ has property $1$ in my question, does it mean $a \neq 0$ ?

Comment: The point I'm trying to get down is why $g(x)=f(x)$ and $a=0$ doesn't work for every function. For instance, consider $f(x)=\delta(x)$. Then $g(x)=0$ and $a=1$ works, but so does $g(x)=\delta(x)$ and $a=0$, or $g(x)=2\delta(x)$ and $a=-1$. What condition do you want on $g$?

Comment: Since you indicate $\underset{\epsilon\to0 }{\text{lim}} \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} f(x)dx = 1$, you need to consider the Fourier series for the Dirac comb (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb#Fourier_series).

Comment: @StevenClark I am sorry Steven, but I am not exactly following how the Fourier series for the Dirac comb would mean in regards to my question. I indicate $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} f(x)dx = 1$ to mean non-vanishing integral, and I take the limit to get a very small slice.

Comment: @MiloMoses ah yes I realize my failure to indicate $g(x)$ should not be 'expressed' in terms of $\delta (x)$. I realize this is not rigorous in the slightest but $g(x)$ would be a 'normal' function, that would help 'build' $f(x)$ in terms of the dirac delta. I drew a quick paint to kind of illustrate an example of what I mean, where $g(x) = sin(x)$, and I obviously can't place $\delta (0)$ at infinity so it lies just above the graph at $x=0$ https://imgur.com/a/oxkUR69

Comment: The Fourier series for the Dirac comb is consistent with $\underset{\epsilon\to 0 }{\text{lim}} \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} f(x)\,dx=1$, but the Dirac comb consists of an infinite number of Dirac delta functions which are periodic. So the fouriwe series for the Dirac comb is equivalent to $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-k T)$.

Comment: It is not true that $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+}\int_{|x|\le  \varepsilon}f(x)\,dx=1$ implies that $f(x)=g(x)+\delta(x)$.  Note that the distributional derivative of the Dirac Delta, $\delta'$ satisfies $$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+}\int_{|x|\le  \varepsilon}\delta'(x)\,dx=0$$So, $f(x) +\delta(x)+\delta'(x)$ also works and is a different distribution from $f(x)+\delta(x)$.